# I keep getting the error of referencing a local variable before assignment! how do I solve this?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, variables, error-handling

thanks for taking the time to help me out. I am writing a web scraping api in django but have been getting a terrible error for the past 5 days! the weird thing is that on macOS there is absolutely NO error and when I deploy to AWS it throws the variable referencing error at me! ubuntu has python 3.6.8 and macOS has python 3.6.6

I have already tried different methods but now I cannot think of any! the scraped data which should be returned returns fine on macOS but on ubuntu I am getting crushed! please help!

```
data_list = []
div_class = scrape_driver_2.find(class_ = 'c1_t2i')
daraz_products = scrape_driver.find_all(class_ = 'c2prKC')

for data_fragment in daraz_products: # iterate and find all classes 
    data_block = data_fragment.text.strip()  # Convert code to text
    formatted_block = data_block.replace('ADD TO CART', '')

    second_iterated_block = formatted_block.replace('%', '')
    third_iterated_block = second_iterated_block.replace(')Pakistan', ')-Pakistan')

    fourth_iterated_block = third_iterated_block.replace('Pakistan', '-Pakistan')

    data_list.append(fourth_iterated_block)
    high_data = [{"Timestamp": time_stamp,
                  "TS Token": ts_token,
                  "Status": sitrep},
                  data_list] 

return Response({"data": high_data})
engine_initializer.close()
```

The error I get is :
UnboundLocalError at /api/big-budget-filter/
local variable 'high_data' referenced before assignment

Comment: it means `daraz_products` is empty, and hence `high_data` is never set.

Comment: It's probably that `daraz_products` was empty. Please always paste the complete error traceback in your questions, so that we don't have to guess where the error happened.

Comment: this exact same code piece scrapes ALL products on macOS, sir on ubuntu this error is piercing the h311 out of me!

Comment: @Ali_Rashid: well then likely the webpage you scrape is not accessible, or renders different content for a different agent.

Comment: UnboundLocalError at /api/big-budget-filter/
local variable 'high_data' referenced before assignment
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value: 
local variable 'high_data' referenced before assignment
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/Exodis-Django/Exodis-Django-

Comment: how come high_data variable is accessible on Mac? but on AWS ubuntu it does this?

Comment: after appending the data_list with the scraped data I assign it to high_data inside the for loop and need to return it as a response but then that error pops on ubuntu

Comment: high_data is declared inside the for loop, on macOS works perfectly but not AWS ubuntu :( someone save my code here!

Comment: @Ali_Rashid, you could create `high_data` variable outside scope, but not sure why you did that because after each loop, your `high_data` will change the value so.. not sure that is your expected or not

Comment: how? after data_list is appended it needs to be passed with the appended data to high_data INSIDE the loop and then returned, if I do it outside the loop then I get an empty list!

Comment: how can I make a variable high_data outside the loop and then it can change in the for loop and then be returned? something like that I think...

Answer (score 0):

Keep high_data outside of the loop and set it after all iterations before returning.

```py
data_list = []
div_class = scrape_driver_2.find(class_ = 'c1_t2i')
daraz_products = scrape_driver.find_all(class_ = 'c2prKC')

for data_fragment in daraz_products: # iterate and find all classes 
    data_block = data_fragment.text.strip()  # Convert code to text
    formatted_block = data_block.replace('ADD TO CART', '')

    second_iterated_block = formatted_block.replace('%', '')
    third_iterated_block = second_iterated_block.replace(')Pakistan', ')-Pakistan')

    fourth_iterated_block = third_iterated_block.replace('Pakistan', '-Pakistan')

    data_list.append(fourth_iterated_block)



high_data = [{"Timestamp": time_stamp,
                  "TS Token": ts_token,
                  "Status": sitrep},
                  data_list] 

return Response({"data": high_data})
```

EDIT: a simplified example version with dummy data, as per comments of this post

```py
data_list = []

daraz_products = ["prod1","prod2","prod3"]

for data_fragment in daraz_products:
     data_list.append(data_fragment)

print data_list
```

data_list will contain all products from daraz_products

Comment: tried that sir, oh well I can try again but the funny thing is my code works on macOS without error but on AWS ubuntu it throws errors!

Comment: It will return nothing except that empty ```data_list```

Comment: it has to append the data list with the scraped data then pass APPENDED data_list to high_data and return high_data

Comment: That doesnt make sense, You are appending data to a list inside the loop. Once appended it wont be empty after the final iteration.

Comment: I know its weird, I'm texting out your suggested method now I hope it works but how come my code which is having errors on AWS ubuntu is not working but on macOS it works?

Comment: I just tested your method out on macOS but on AWS I got no data just the timestamp stuff and an empty list

Comment: Like others said,  if `daraz_products = scrape_driver.find_all(class_ = 'c2prKC')` returns nothing then no iterations of the loop happen and high_data doesnt get set. You can simulate this on your macOS but replacing `daraz_products = scrape_driver.find_all(class_ = 'c2prKC')` with `daraz_products = []` and youll probably get the same error

Comment: sir sir it WORKS on MacOS but when I do it on AWS ubuntu it returns NOTHING!

Comment: Yes i understand that! my point is that on AWS `daraz_products = scrape_driver.find_all(class_ = 'c2prKC')` is not returning any data which is causing the rest of the code to fail.

Comment: I am using selenium Firefox headless to go to the Daraz.pk website then beautiful soup to scrape the products

Comment: so do you think it is a problem on AWS? I am using Firefox and gecko driver but the problem is there Is no UI only a terminal screen so...

Comment: wait wait wait! maybe I should not use selenium to visit the url to scrape! I should use requests!

Comment: I think this is now out of scope of this question. Good luck hopefully this has helped